# Pie Chart displaying just one data label - SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, ssrs-2012

It´s simple. I have a dataset configured and this dataset returns 3 different values.

I just want to put these values into a chart and show it´s labels.

I´m able to put them into the chart but only the first one display the data label as you can see on the image below.

Someone to give me some light, please? =)

[image]

Comment: do you want to display the max one or the first one?

Comment: @BhupeshC Imagine that I have 3 values. 15  |  26  |  74
I want to create a pie chart with them (I could do this) and also put the data label on the chart, but, as you can see on the image above, just the first value is been printing on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. It's still an issue in the latest version of ReportBuilder (SSRS 2016).

After nearly three years you may have found a way already, but the only way I know of has been answered here: [Pie chart not showing all the values in SSRS 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035896/pie-chart-not-showing-all-the-values-in-ssrs-2014)

The trick is to first create a line chart, add all values and then right-click each individual line to be able to activate "Show data labels" for each line. After that's done change the chart type to your pie chart and you will see all labels.

Please note you will lose any pie chart-related visual modifications once you change the chart type. So the best way is to start with the line chart, add the data labels for each line, change to a pie chart and **then** do any  further modifications.