# Pie chart not showing all the values in SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, pie-chart

I created the pie chart in SSRS as given below. I enabled the labels by right clicking on pie chart and click show labels. When I preview the chart I cant see all the labels. The only label visible is for the biggest portion in the pie. I tried to increase the size of the chart but no effect. Any idea?[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No info is available but finally I learned the trick. I think there is a bug because of which only one label is shown (403 in my case) on the pie chart. To solve the problem follow the steps:

1. Right click on the pie chart and change it to line chart.
2. Now on individual bar right click and select show labels from the menu.
3. Do it for all the 4 or more bars.
4. Change your chart type back to pie chart and preview the pie chart

Every label will appear now.